# plaid accesstoken failed while passing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, plaid

I have used plaid in my iOS app I am getting alert like failed to get access token while passing the plaid datas to the webservice can you please tel me public token and access token are different ? This webservice is working fine in the android

Answer (score 0):

The public_token is ephemeral and expires after 30 minutes. A public_token becomes invalidated once it has been successfully exchanged for an access_token.

Store access tokens and items in your application database
access_tokens and item_ids are the core identifiers that map your end-users to their financial institutions. You should persist these securely and associate them with users of your application. Make sure, however, that these identifiers are never exposed client-side.

https://plaid.com/docs/api/#storing-plaid-api-identifiers